# Cakephp 2 Auth white screen of death

Tags: cakephp-2.0, authentication

Problem: Whenever trying to access a page with requires authorisation, I get a white screen, no redirect to login nothing. Also when trying to login, it just redirects back to the login page with no login error (it does try and go through the login process).
The pages in question go through the beforeFilter but when it goes to the AUTH stage it dies.

I have:

Set the /app/tmp/cache folder is writeable and I cleared any files from the models, persistent etc... folders

Debug is set to 2

It was working absolutely fine early today until I performed some updates.

It works fine on my development machine.

Built over 20 CakePHP sites from 1.2 to 2.1 and this white screen is bloody annoying.

I don't have access to the PHP logs as it's a shared hosting server.

Any ideas where I can look to try and find the problem?

Comment: Found the problem after 6 hours of bashing my head against the keyboard. In the app controller there was a new line before the first opening php tag.

Comment: About the PHP logs, they can be found in \app\tmp\logs of your cake app